# Pros / cons browser querying front end server to query separate backend Vs directly query backend

Tags: api, cross-domain, microservices

I have a front end written in react and a backend API which connects to a db for getting data. They have been written separately and are different services.

The front end server has a bunch of routes that connect to the backend API and I'm wondering what are the pros / cons of having these routes instead of directly accessing the backend API?

An example of the structure:

1. Front end server serves index.html and browser.js.
2. Browser.js makes GET, POST, PUT requests to front end server.
3. Front end server takes these requests and then makes a GET, POST, PUT request to the backend API.

Alternative:

1. Front end server serves index.html and browser.js.
2. Browser.js makes GET, POST, PUT requests to backend API.

So what are the pros / cons of doing it either way? The prior developer before me told me they did it the first way to bypass CORS and obscure the IP address of the backend API. However that doesn't seem to me like it is worth the trouble considering all the extra code, tests, etc the front end server has to write and maintain, in addition to extra network hops. I'm wondering if I'm missing some other more crucial reason that my inexperience cannot see? (My gut says do it the second way). Note that we are in a microservices architecture .

Answer (score 0):

> Front end server takes these requests and then makes a GET, POST, PUT request to the backend API.

The pattern that you describe is called [API Gateway](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) and it has the following characteristics:

**Benefits:**

- Insulates the clients from how the application is partitioned into microservices
- Insulates the clients from the problem of determining the locations of service instances
- Provides the optimal API for each client
- Reduces the number of requests/roundtrips. For example, the API gateway enables clients to retrieve data from multiple services with a single round-trip. Fewer requests also means less overhead and improves the user experience. An API gateway is essential for mobile applications.
- Simplifies the client by moving logic for calling multiple services from the client to API gateway
- Translates from a “standard” public web-friendly API protocol to whatever protocols are used internally

**Drawbacks:**

- Increased complexity - the API gateway is yet another moving part that must be developed, deployed and managed
- Increased response time due to the additional network hop through the API gateway - however, for most applications the cost of an extra roundtrip is insignificant.

**Conclusion:** if you don't need the advantages that the API Gateway provides then you should not use it.

Comment: I'm not talking about the API gateway pattern. I'm talking about the front end server existing to bypass CORS and to obfuscate backend API. For example in my example the backend API could be an API gateway in both scenarios.

Comment: "Browser.js makes GET, POST, PUT requests to backend API" - this does not seem like a Gateway API

Comment: I understand what you are saying. " obfuscate backend API" - why would you want to obfuscate that api?

Comment: @Contstantin probably for security reasons? Full disclosure, the developers before me wrote some questionable code so I'm not sure if this is one of those instances where they didn't know what they were doing, or if they had a good reason for doing this...

Comment: But if even if you hide it, the frontend server would still forward request to that "bad" api anyway.